# What is the correct way to visualise and think about vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

A vector space is a set of vectors over a field. Generally, it helps me to think about them as a sort of bubble or sphere encompassing all of the vectors in the set. However it occurred to me that it is probably wrong to think about them this way.

How should I visualise vector spaces?

Comment: A bubble or sphere makes it sound to me like they are bounded, enclosed, compact, or similar which a vector space generally is not.  As for visualization, the easiest to visualize would probably be $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ in the usual way.  Finite dimensional vector spaces act very similarly... you have some set of "cardinal directions" (*basis vectors*) from which you can form any desired direction with any distance you like using a linear combination of these.  The space itself being the realm in which these resulting combinations of directions with distance exist.

Comment: Linear combinations of basis vectors is what leads me to think about a sort of unbounded area which contains all of the possible combinations of vectors. Perhaps a bubble is the wrong word?